# Python process text file with a mix of data

Tags: python, json, dictionary, text, find

following to my previous question..I simplified it...I need to process a text file. Need to read text file, detect specific word and process the next few lines than continue read the file, detect some word and process the next few lines. How can we done this is python.

The text file consists information of network devices and the information is non-structure format and the format of the information different of each network device. I need to check if detect few words process few lines below it and once complete save it onto json file. Than continue read the file and detect the words and process few lines below it... for example below .. detect AAA and process all the line before line 'Done!'...than continue read the file and if detect vendor AAA, BBB and CCC run process the line before line 'Done!'. Process of each vendors will be different and the process will end with line Done!

For example below

```
vendor: AAA
ID:1
line3-------------
line4------------
line5------------
Done!

vendor:BBB
ID:5
line10-------------
line11-----------
line12------------
line13-------------
line14------------
line15------------
Done!

vendor:CCC
ID:10
line20-------------
line21------------
line22------------
line23-------------
Done!

vendor:BBB
ID:8
line28-------------
line29------------
line30------------
line31-------------
line32------------
line33------------
Done!

vendor: AAA
ID:4
line38-------------
line39------------
line40------------
Done!
```

Than each of the process for each ID will be save on a json file

This is what I have done so far

```
with open("outputFile.txt", "r") as file:
   for line in file:
      if 'AAA' in line:
         next(file)
         data = [line.strip().split() for line in file]
         print("This is AAA") 

         dict = {"scan":[]}
         for x in data:
            --extract line of data below ID--

         with open('outputAAA.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(dict, f)
      elif 'BBB' in line:
         next(file)
         data = [line.strip().split() for line in file]
         print("This is BBB") 

         dict = {"scan":[]}
         for x in data:
            --extract line of data below ID--

         with open('outputBBB.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(dict, f)
      elif 'CCC' in line:
         next(file)
         data = [line.strip().split() for line in file]
         print("This is CCC") 

         dict = {"scan":[]}
         for x in data:
            --extract line of data below ID--

         with open('outputCCC.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(dict, f)
      else:
         print("No vendor recognised")
         continue
```

The problem...

1. it will create json file of AAA, BBB and CCC
2. it will overwrite json file
3. Read file somehow not continue at the last point. What I mean here... after detect for example AAA...process line 3 to 5 and write json file and than continue start read again the last line and detect either AAA, BBB or CCC... if detect BBB...process the next few lines till line Done!... than continue read the file...and if detect AAA again... run the process for AAA... and so on...
4. Iteration not properly run to detect and run the process accordingly.

Appreciate for some advise on how to do it in python...thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to file I/O, follow [a guide](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python) to get yourself started.

It appears that your JSON is getting overwritten each time it is opened in your if else statements. The mode you are opening with `'w'` will overwrite the file if it already exists. If you want to add on to the end, you will need to use the `'a'` mode to append on to the end of a file.

```
with open('outputBBB.json', 'a') as f
```

Comment: the script should run every hour and if using 'a'... the content in json file will be duplicate.. The idea is every 1 hour must overwrite the json file

Comment: Should the json file be overwritten every hour?